# How to save form data into database in android sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I need help with adding a database in my app for android. What I want to do is save name, address, if certain checkboxes are checked and textbox data. so far this is what I have in my main activity xml and java (download links):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp4fg0f5kx0p5it/activity_main.xml?dl=1

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2dkqtoe8h1dl85/MainActivity.java?dl=1

All the other questions and tutorials just don't seem able to be grasped by my mind. I want to save the "name", "address", "AirSealing", "airsealnotes", "DuctSealing", "BlowerDoor", "ductsealnotes", "blowdoornotes", "Light", "lightnotes", "othernotes", "HPD", "HPGJGNY", "Placeholder", and the save button to save data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **lot** of boilerplate code associated with creating and handling an SQLite database (even just one with a single table), so don't feel bad about not getting it right away.

Here's the tutorial I personally used to grasp SQLite databases in Android:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Essentially, you'll want to follow the tutorial, only replacing their columns (a name and phone number) with the data you want to store. The custom helper class isn't mandatory - you can simply take the code they put in the DB handler class and write it in your main activity class instead - but it makes writing and retrieving data a lot easier.

Also, a word of warning: you won't be able to store *every* type of data in a database out of the box. For instance, if you want to store a `boolean` (which would be your checkboxes), you'll have to do it by storing, say, an integer or a string, instead of an actual boolean.

Comment: thank you for the tutorial, i now know how to set it up and add the strings, but how do I save the text into that string, or add an integer value for the checkboxes?

Comment: Ah, you mean how to extract the value from the views you've got in your activity? That's pretty simple, you just have to get the View (text, checkbox, etc.) via findViewById() in your activity, and then extract the value from the public method that returns it. For instance, for an EditText view, you need to get the value by calling yourEditText.getText(), which you then just store in a String. Hope that made some sense.

Comment: `// getting address
 public String getAddress(){
  return this._address;
 }
 
 // setting address
 public void setAddress(String Address){
  this._phone_number = address;
 }` does this work?